# How do Bluetooth profiles work?

Tags: bluetooth

I understand that Bluetooth profiles consist of other profiles and protocols. What I don't understand is exactly how Bluetooth devices interact with each other. For example, if you take any accessory that implements the A2DP profile and connect it to the iPad then the iPad will stream all audio output to it. This makes me believe that a profile is nothing more than a modular component in a well-defined eco-system. For instance, a web-browser can use any one of your choice of search-engines in the toolbar; would I be correct in saying that the iPad is the equivalent of the browser and the A2DP accessory is the equivalent of the search-engine? Would I also be correct in saying that the use of A2DP is entirely up to the device it's paired with? That is, Apple could have instead chosen (albeit unwisely) to make the iPad output only key-clicks and ring-tones to it, correct? So there's nothing inherent in the A2DP profile that says "All devices using the A2DP profile MUST output all audio to it" right?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% familiar with Bluetooth as a whole.  I've been spending some time drafting a profile for BT Low-Energy, so someone might be able to provide insight on standard Bluetooth with a little more detail.

But, from what I understand, the profiles are essentially a large map of connected references.  So the A2DP profile will have a list of attributes, or rather, a list of HEX values which point to attributes within the larger profile.  These attribute are typically universally available to all profiles, but only implemented by the profile where they are needed.  These attributes define some piece of information that is going to be transmitted.  This profile needs to be on both device to communicate, because this allows to Bluetooth transmissions to be smaller by only referencing a commonly known definition of the data it is transmitting (rather than defining what the data is in every transmission like some communication types).

So for A2DP, the transmission might be something very simple like '0x1351458 0', which tails the device that whatever that profile attribute is, it's value is 0.  So that attribute might be the "play" attribute, so setting to 0 might stop the music.

Again, this is how I understand Bluetooth profiles from the Low-Energy standpoint which tends to be more a transmission of state than actual data, so it might differ a bit with regular Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth profiles are specifications of bluetooth protocols that are implemented on the host side in bluetooth protocol stack.

Following link by bluetooth.org will provide basics about bluetooth profiles
https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/Profiles.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Bluetooth Profiles are set of standard interoperable guidelines defined by bluetooth.org, to ensure interoperability between different bluetooth devices.

Bluetooth devices claiming to support bluetooth profiles, should get Bluetooth Qualification Board[BQB] certified for interoperability.

You can buy any device supporting A2DP and test with any tablet/computers[which has bluetooth A2DP profile supported].

A2DP is not specific to iPad. It is a generic profile that stands for Advanced Audio Distribution Profile for exchanging Audio between two bluetooth devices.

Comment: I'm sorry but this answer is so generic that it in no way answers my question; this is the very same information that I can get by a quick google. I am looking for confirmation on my specific questions.

Comment: could I be correct in saying that the iPad is the equivalent of the browser and the A2DP accessory is the equivalent of the search-engine?

Comment: if you like to have some extensive reading on A2DP , I suggest to visit bluetooth.org , check for A2dp. Apologies of being so generic in my first reply

Comment: My question has nothing to do with A2DP, I simply used A2DP as an example to get my point across.